# How to delete a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Using this we can create procedure then how to delete,alter...etc,Can any one help me how to delete procedure.

```
USE [PSI Data]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure[dbo].[savepsi]
 @Psiid int,
 @Name varchar(50),
 @DOB int,
 @Sex varchar(50),
 @Mobile int,
 @Cusaddress varchar(50),
 @Product varchar(50),
 @Amount int

 as

 begin

 insert Psitable(Psiid,Name,DOB,Sex,Mobile,Cusaddress,Product,Amount)
 Values (@Psiid,@Name,@DOB,@Sex,@Mobile,@Cusaddress,@Product,@Amount)

 end
```

Comment: `DROP PROCEDURE savepsi`... ?

Comment: what is 'GO'? the delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

USE [PSI Data]
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[savepsi];
GO

Answer (score 3):

To remove a stored procedure you can use the command [`DROP PROCEDURE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174969.aspx)

```
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[savepsi]
```

Comment: The question is asking how to do it in .net. all you've done is supply some sql

Comment: @PreetSangha the answer doesn't change no matter where you do it from; and actually, if the OP *does* mean "from .NET", then this answer is "correct", and Nick's is "wrong" (`GO` is not actually TSQL)

Comment: @PreetSangha - how is the OP asking to do it in .NET when he has provided a SQL Stored procedure?

Comment: @DarrenDavies - question has been edited so my comment no longer applies

Answer (score 2):

**Use Syntax:-**

```
DROP PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_NAME;

         OR

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedureName;
```

ie.

```
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[savepsi];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.savepsi;
```

Comment: @PreetSangha I do not accept the assertion that the OP actually means from .NET; nothing in the question is .NET

Comment: Comment removed. As it no longer applies

Comment: You please check the Tag added with the question. And I only provide the way in which we can delete the OP.

Comment: Who are you that you down the answer of others ??

Comment: If it is helpful to you then please mark it as Correct answer so that other get it.

Comment: Most welcome.. If it helpful to you then mark it as correct answer, which will help to other persons.